# Loading Image in android using Picasso shows wrong orientation while uploading from IOS?

Tags: android, image-processing, picasso

I'm displaying images in my app by fetching them from server using a url,

while displaying them, the images uploaded by android phones are displayed correct orientation but the images uploaded by IOS are displayed in landscape orientation!

I'm using Picasso for loading images

```
urlFeed = itemList.get(position).getImg().getJSONObject(0).getString("img");

Picasso.with(context).load(urlFeed)
                                .fit().centerCrop()
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.wineplaceholder)
                                .into(holder2.userReviewProductIv);
```

Comment: show your ios code

Comment: IOS is handled by some other team! I don't have access to that code

Comment: What version of picasso are you using?

Comment: The latest version! 2.5.2